# Hiding GLFW includes

Tags: c++, glfw

I have a C++ class for my OpenGL window, but it includes headers for GLEW and GLFW, which I am trying to avoid to make the code cleaner as this is part of a library and I don't want to have to include GLEW and GLFW headers twice. Is there a trick I haven't thought of how to do this please?

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <IWindow.h>
#include <string>

class Window : public IWindow
{
public:
    Window(int width, int height, std::string caption,
        bool fullscreen = false);

    ~Window();

protected:
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    std::string m_caption;
    GLFWwindow *m_window;
    GLFWmonitor *m_monitor;
    bool m_fullscreen;

    static void KeyInputCallBack(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode,
        int action, int mods);
        
    static void CursorPositionCallBack(GLFWwindow *window, double xPos,
    double yPos);

    static void CallbackResize(GLFWwindow* window, int cx, int cy);
};
```

Comment: [Forward declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class)? `class GLFWwindow;` `class GLFWmonitor;`?

Comment: You have to use the [tag:glfw] tag for questions about GLFW, but not the [tag:opengl] tag. GLFW != OpenGL

Comment: Rabbid76 Thank you, brain wasn't working..

Comment: Make an abstract baseclass with abstractions you want to use (an interface). Make a factory for it and a GLFW implementation. Added bonus you can inject a mock into your code for unit testing. (See dependency injection)

Comment: `protected` smells like inheritance. Aren't there better FCoI solutions for this problem? (favor composition over inheritance)

Comment: First of all, you have to include the GLFW and GLEW headers only once. You put the initialization into the library source, from there, in your applications, you only include your window header and call your library init function (either invoke manually or via constructor of singleton object). Hiding all the symbols of the GLFW library would also mean, that you'd have to replace them if they are going to be used (which involves introducing new typedefs and constants, basically cloning/translating existing code - idk, if that is making your code much cleaner).